# Decoding strange user agent header

Tags: http, user-agent

In my project we have a strange bug in html/js that we can hardly mimic in staging environment, so we started tracking a few things once we detect the bug, inclding the user-agent header.

So now I have a trouble decoding a few of then:

```
mozilla/5.0 windows nt 10.0 wow64 applewebkit/537.36 khtml
mozilla/5.0 windows nt 10.0 win64 x64 applewebkit/537.36 khtml
mozilla/5.0 windows nt 6.1 win64 x64 applewebkit/537.36 khtml
mozilla/5.0 windows nt 6.1 wow64 applewebkit/537.36 khtml
mozilla/5.0 windows nt 6.3 wow64 applewebkit/537.36 khtml
```

I can clearly see these are windows machines, non IE, non Egde browser. Firefox and Chrome have different user-agent either. But what exactly browser it is? Maybe it is a browser with some privace/no-track setting/addon?

Comment: Here are some valuable informations [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Answer (score 0):

The issiue is fixed, strange user agents where actually google chrome browsers.

We use datadog metrics and tags via statsd java client to gather these error. It appears that comma in tag (e.g. chrome user agent) caused the rest of tag sring to be dropped.

Not sure whether it's datadog or statsd client at fault.